# AWK fails numeric comparison when field is text

Tags: awk

AWK seems to fail a numeric comparison when the field is text.

```
% cat tt
1 2 3
a 100 c
x y z


% awk '{if($2>10){print}}' tt
a 100 c
x y z
```

Expecting to see only 'a 100 c'. What's the trick ?

Comment: If you are going "text", then your comparison is "y">"10". And because "y">"1" (check ASCII codes), it fulfills the conditional guard and gets printed.

Comment: Simplified `awk '$2+0>10' tt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Comparison-Operators.html

"Comparison expressions have the value one if true and zero if false. When comparing operands of mixed types, numeric operands are converted to strings using the value of CONVFMT (see section Conversion of Strings and Numbers)."

Force a numeric comparison:

```
% awk '{if($2+0>10){print}}' tt
a 100 c
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Strings-And-Numbers.html#Strings-And-Numbers

Comment: don't need to write out the `print` and `if`statements explicitly, just `awk '$2+0 > 10' tt` would suffice